# updating firebase hosted flutter web app issue

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase-hosting

I have a flutter web app hosted through firebase. However, I have been unable to update the web app. The `public` folder is what is deployed to firebase when I run firebase deploy. When I run `flutter clean` and then `flutter web build` no errors are thrown but the `/build/web` directory doesn't update so I have nothing to put in the `public` folder. Any recommendations on how to fix?